# Getline to get stdin is being skipped

Tags: c, stdin, getline

I'm trying to get input from the user in the console, but I'm having problems with the function getline() in my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //check that the number of arguments given is valid
    if (argc != 2){
        printf("Error: arguments. \nThe file should only take one argument which is the name of the level\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char test[5];
    int nb_lettres=strlen(argv[1]);
    strncpy(test,argv[1]+nb_lettres-4,4);
    //check that the file given is either a .tgz or a .tar
    test[4]='\0';
    if(strcmp(test,".tar")!=0 && strcmp(test,".tgz")!=0)
    {
        printf("Error: arguments. \nThe argument should be a file having the extension .tar or .tgz \n");
        exit(2);
    }
    int status; //START OF THE PART CONTAINING THE PROBLEM
    pid_t pid;
    //create the folder then move to it, then extract the tar
    if((pid=fork())!=0){
        if(fork()){
            execlp("mkdir","mkdir","leaSHdir",NULL);
        }
        //waiting to make sure we don't try to go in the folder before it's fully created
        wait(&status);
        execlp("tar","tar", "-xf", argv[1], "-C", "leaSHdir/",NULL);
    }
    waitpid(pid,&status,0);
    printf("Extracting the files..\n");
    sleep(1);   //END OF THE PART CONTAINING THE PROBLEM
    //Read the meta file
    FILE *file;
    chdir("./leaSHdir");

    file=fopen("meta","r");
    if (file==NULL){
        //  printf("Oh dear, something went wrong with read()! %s\n", strerror(errno));
        printf("Error: meta. \nImpossible to read the meta file. Please check that it does exist (without looking in, vile cheater)\n");
        exit(3);

}
char *line=NULL;
size_t len=0; 
        //Saving the commands which will be used by the user
char *result=NULL;
char **commands = malloc(5 * sizeof *commands);
int i=0;
if(commands==NULL){
    printf("Error: memory. \nA problem occured with the memory while creating a pointer\n");
    exit(4);
}
while(getline(&line,&len,file)!=-1){
    if(strstr(line,"$")!=NULL){
        commands[i]=(malloc(strlen(line)));
        strcpy(commands[i],line+2); 
                    //if the array is full,we add space for the next incoming command
        if(i >= 4){
            commands=realloc(commands,sizeof *commands *(i+2));
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(line[0]=='>'){
        result=malloc(strlen(line));
        strcpy(result,line+2);
        }
}
int a = 0;
for (a = 0;a<i;a++){
    printf("%s",commands[a]);
}
printf("%s",result);
printf("Erasing meta..");
unlink("meta");
printf("meta erased.\n");
int c;

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){
        printf("rien\n");
    }
ssize_t r = getline(&line,&len,stdin); 
printf("%d '%s' %d",(int) r, line, c);
char machin[2555];
scanf("%s",machin);
printf("%s test",machin);
free(commands);
free(result);
return 0;
}
```

When I execute this code, the last getline is completely skipped (the first one is working without any problem), which I don't see why. I've also tried using different functions (fgets, scanf) and both were also skipped. 
Thanks in advance for any help which can be provided :)

Edit:
Changed the faulty getline line with `ssize_t r = getline(&line,&len,stdin); printf("%d '%s' %d",(int) r, line, c);`, here's the result:

```
cat
ls
man
Bravo! C'est ici!//this line and the 3 other lines before are the lines read by the first getline which is working
Erasing meta..meta erased.
-1 '> Bravo! C'est ici! 
' -1
```

So basically, I don't even have time to type anything, I get this result directly without entering anything. Also the content of  `line` isn't changed after the second `getline` considering it still contains the result from the first `getline`.
Edit 2 :
Okay, I think I found from where comes the problem: Basically, it's from a part of the code i didn't put in the extract there because I though it was not related at all with my current problem, so I've edited the whole extract to put it fully. I've put two comments to mark the part containing the problem. Although I don't see what could be causing it, considering this part contains only forks.
Although, sorry for the trouble, guys, should have put the whole code at the start

Last edit:
Figured out what was the problem: `if((pid=fork())!=0){` which means that once my forks ended I was working on the child process and not on the father as I thought. Once I've changed it to `if((pid=fork())==0){` everything worked fine. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845).

Comment: Suggest: Change `char c;` -- > `int c;` so the `EOF` difference is maintained from the other 256 values returned from getchar().

Comment: Change `getline(&line,&len,stdin); printf("%s",line);` to `if (getline(&line,&len,stdin) > 0); printf("%s",line);`  If EOF occurs, there is nothing to print.

Comment: @Deduplicator that question really needs an update. What has been said in 2009 isn't totally true today.

Comment: @Igor: It's still true that explicitly casting a `void*` is at best bad style, a waste of time and unneccessary clutter for readers. Also, the advice to use `sizeof` on expressions/variables instead of types also still holds. What exactly should be "updated"?

Comment: What text are you inputting such that "the last getline is completely skipped"?  IOW, what do you see that resulted in concluding that getline is completely skipped?  Suggest using `ssize_t r = getline(&line,&len,stdin); printf("%d '%s' %d",(int) r, line, c);` to get a better idea of what is happening in the end.

Comment: @Deduplicator The second point of the highest upvoted answer is rubbish: "It can hide an error, if you forgot to include <stdlib.h>. This can cause crashes, in the worst case."

Comment: @Igor: Depends on your warning/error settings. If you use sane settings (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` + standard-selection), implicit declaration will certainly ring the warning bell. Doesn't make itwrong though.

Comment: @Deduplicator Won't it ring the warning bell even if you don't have those settings on the newest gcc compiler?

Comment: @Igor: There's not only gcc, and certainly not only the newest version. And I don't know (Though I suspect yes).

Comment: @Deduplicator Removed the casts on the mallocs, thanks for telling me about the fact it's bad to do it :)

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, the newest gcc will. So the response (or at least a part of it) is outdated

Comment: @Igor: You are still ignoring the facts that 1) gcc is not the only compiler there is, and 2) the newest version is not all there is. Actually, sometimes (embedded mostly, though 16-bit desktop probably too), you can be forced to use a severly dated version, or even a completely different compiler.

Comment: @jilako: Did you also see how you can use `sizeof` in a less error-prone way, by avoiding types?

Comment: @Deduplicator You mean by replacing for exemple `malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(line))` with `malloc(sizeof * strlen(line)` ?

Comment: @jilako For strings, use `malloc(strlen(line) + 1)`.  Else consider style `commands = realloc(commands, N * sizeof *commands);`.

Comment: No, more like `malloc(1+strlen(line))`. (You don't use `sizeof` on `char`, because a char is never more or less than one char big). But, e.g. `T* x = malloc(count * sizeof*x)` instead of `T* x = malloc(count * sizeof(T))`. See the dereference I did?

Comment: I see, though, what is the kind of error which could happen by using the types in it?

Comment: @jilako Using c_orrect_ types in `malloc()` is not a problem, but using @Deduplicator suggestion, code is, IMO, _less likely_ to have a mis-matched size calculation. Example `char **commands=malloc(sizeof(char**)*5);` should be `char **commands=malloc(sizeof(char*)*5);`,  In this case, the `sizeof(char *)` is likely the same as `sizeof(char **)`, but by using `char **commands = malloc(5 * sizeof *commands);` is certainly correct, easier to code and to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit]

After some edits:
OP's problem occurs when using `stdin` after `fork()`.

Similar to [Two processes reading the same stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880157/two-processes-reading-the-same-stdin)

---

Code is unable to take in additional input as `stdin` has all ready reached the `EOF` condition or a rare IO error.  That is the `-1` return values from `getline()` and `getchar()`.  `line` simply retains its former contents as nothing was changed.

```
char c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
ssize_t r = getline(&line,&len,stdin); //getline not working
printf("%d '%s' %d",(int) r, line, c);
```

> -1 '> Bravo! C'est ici!
>   ' -1

---

Additional issue: `realloc()` too late.

`strcpy(commands[5],line+2);` writes to unallocated memory.

```
char **commands=malloc(sizeof(char**)*5);
int i=0;
...
// In loop, i becomes 5.
...
strcpy(commands[i],line+2); 
if (i > 5){
  commands=realloc(commands,sizeof(char**)*(i+2));
```

Comment: I see, but how would I then able to get input from stdin, considering the last `getline` in the code is the only time where I try to get input from stdin? Isn't `while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);` supposed to flush the stdin?

Comment: Hmmm.  Thinking code may be faulty in other places and the the `getline()` issues results from that.  E.g. (in 2 places) `commands[i]=(malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(line))); strcpy(commands[i],line+2);` is a problem as `line+2` could be beyond the end of `line`.  I'll look more.  IAC, `getline()` is working, it is just that `stdin` has read EOF.  BTW: after seeing "meta erased.", do you type anything?  Are you using redirected input?

Comment: @jilako Check appended answer.

Comment: I corrected the realloc so it happens earlier, also changed the mallocs following your and deduplicator's instructions, but the problem still happens. After "meta erased" appears on screen, i don't have time to type anything, it prompts me directly with the result from the next printf, then the program ends.

Comment: The `line+2` shouldn't be a problem because line is supposed to contain text only having this format "$ text" or "> text" (I know it's not really safe, but I'm mostly concerned by the problem with the `getline()` first)

Comment: I've edited my code so it contains the whole code,considering the problem seems to have come from a part I thought unrelated. It would seem the problem is caused by one of the two execlp in my forks, though I don't see how they can have effect on stdin..

Comment: Are you using redirected input?

Comment: `char test[4]; ... test[4]='\0';` is bad as `test` is only 4 `char` long.  Further `strncpy()` is not used correctly.  Try char test[4+1]; strncpy(test, ..., 4); test[4]='\0';`

Comment: I've modified the variable test. As for redirected input, as far as i know, I'm not using any, but I'm not used to execs functions =/

Comment: `char test[4]; ...  test[5]='\0';` is bad.  Suggest `char test[4+1]; ...  test[4]='\0';`  Recall index addressing is 0-based.

Comment: Woops, my bad there, changed wrong position, should be right now

Comment: Hmmm, Maybe your forking does not allow multiple processes to share `stdin`?

Comment: Would seem to be the problem, if I fork , with no instructions but an exit(0) in the children, the problem do happen, but if I comment the whole part with the forks, no problem.. Now I'll have to figure out either how to do it with no fork, or a way to keep stdin working with my forks.. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Put somtehing before getilne to consume the trailing '\n' character. For example:

```
while ( getchar() != '\n' );
getline(&line,&len,stdin);
```

Comment: Code may need to check against `'\n'` and `EOF` to avoid infinite loop with `while ( getchar() != '\n' );`

Comment: Thing is there is already a `while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);` just before, the getline, and it's still getting skipped. I also tried putting a `if` on the `getline` , didn't change anything.